# Переход, нажатием кнопки, между вью

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Этим кодом перехожу между vc свайпом

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController")

self.addChildViewController(vc0!)
self.scrollView.addSubview((vc0?.view)!)
vc0?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewNoteViewController")

var frame1 = vc1?.view.frame
frame1?.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width 
vc1?.view.frame = frame1!
self.addChildViewController(vc1!)
self.scrollView.addSubview((vc1?.view)!)
vc1?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2 , height: self.view.frame.size.height );

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Но не знаю, как нажатием на кнопку переходить между vc1 и vc2

Comment: ну как, хоть один из трех подошел?

Comment: Нет, я сделал по другому

Comment: тогда публикуйте свой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите добавлять view второго контроллера на view первого? Для переходов между контроллерами используйте segue. Добавьте в сториборд UINavigationController, а потом два ваших контроллера, и переход на второй делайте с помощью segue в экшне вашей кнопки, например:

```
func tappedButton(sender: UIButton!) { 
     performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помимо `segue` можно использовать и ваш подход, но немного по-другому. 
Если используете `UINavigationController`, то пригодится метод `push`, в другом случае используйте метод `self.present(viewCOntroller...)`
Не используйте `addChildViewController` для переходов между котроллерами! И не вызывайте `didMove(toParentViewController...)` сами.

Answer (score 0):

Eсли имелось ввиду не переход, а paging между vc0 и vc1.
(сужу по употреблению слова "переход" для paging в начале вопроса)

```
func showPage(index: Int) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width*index, y: 0)
}
```

если нет, то ответы ниже помогут

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй так, если у тебя xcode 8.2.1

```
@IBAction func You_name(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Name_you_Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let vc = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier_you_storibiard"))
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```